# Microsoft Word documents to Wordpress pages adding paragraph tags

Tags: plugins, microsoft

I have read through a variety of different questions here and on Google. I think my question has an answer that I do not want. Anyways, I have been given 10 or so different documents with a fair amount of formatting within each. Each page  needs to be given `<p> </p>`. I fear that the solution is simply coding each and every line. Very tedious but the WordPress paste into doesn't cut it.

Anyone found any good solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just (or mostly) paragraphs then you needn't neither WordPress nor WordPress plugins to be able to do this.

http://word2cleanhtml.com/

Comment: mostly paragraphs, some of the text is bolded, italicized and that's about it. However if I strip it to plaintext I have to go through and add many tags. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: this worked out perfectly. Great advice thank you.